gitlab ce css and js files not serving using Nginx
I installed "Gitlab ce" on my ubuntu server. when I reach Gitlab form my server IP address everything is ok but when I try to serve it using Nginx, It seems that Nginx can't serve js and css files.

I added this to my gitlab.rb (config) file:
external_url 'http://gitlab.mypersonaldomain.com'

and here is my nginx.conf file:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;


        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name gitlab.mypersonaldomain.com;

            location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
                proxy_buffers 16 64k;
                proxy_buffer_size 128k;

                client_max_body_size 250m;
                client_body_buffer_size 128k;

                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_connect_timeout 300;
                proxy_redirect off;
            }

    }

}

and here is the browser console log:
Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

GET http://gitlab.***************.com/assets/webpack/main.4e9cbf4e.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

any help would be appreciated.
